# Резиновый столбец базы SQL, Python

Tags: python, sql

sql_2 = f"SELECT B_ITEM AS C1,COUNT(B_ITEM) AS C2 FROM {table_batch} GROUP BY B_ITEM"

SQL запросом собираю данные с столбца т.е опрашиваю какие значения могут быть и пересчитываю какое количество повторяющихся значений (могут быть: 0001, 0002 и т.д).
После SQL запроса в одну из таблиц в столбце два значения 0004 и 0005, 0004 повторяется 228, 005 повторяется 112 раз. Итого у меня 4 значения, но могут быть 2 или 6 или 8.
Дроблю полученные значения первым кортежем row[0] я получаю имена 0004, 0005, второй кортеж row[1] содержит значения их количества т.е 0004 найдено 228,  005 найдено 112, далее раскидываю их по переменным, проблема в том, что я не знаю в какой следующей таблице в столбце могут быть 1 значение или 2, а может 4.
код у меня написан на два значения и их количество:

```
rows2 = cur2.fetchall()
a, b = [str(row[0]) for row in rows2]
c, d = [int(row[1]) for row in rows2]
```

но этот код уже не работает с одним или тремя, четырьмя значениями. Выходит ошибка:

> *a, b = [str(row[0]) for row in rows2]
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)*

Как сделать чтобы код подстраивался под резиновый столбец и количество переменных менялось в зависимости от количества данных?

Comment: ну так присваивайте результат не двум переменным, а списку. res = [], затем res = [str(row[0]) for row in rows2]

Comment: спасибо @strawdog